# how to reenable php_fileinfo extension after compile php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was compiling php5.5, and add the option --disable-fileinfo by mistake. so it cause exceptions while I upload file in laravel5.

```
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)
```

so I want to enable this php_fileinfo extension, should I recompile php5.5 again?

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried un-commenting `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` from php.ini config file and restarting the server?

Comment: I am in linux, maybe it`s not work for me. and I have found a solution: use phpize to compile fileinfo from source to enable it.

Comment: You should answer your own question with the steps you have taken to solve this and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new to stackoverflow. 
I found my solution here: [install extension from source](http://www.sitepoint.com/install-php-extensions-source/)
thanks @Aziz Saleh